# Find point with two-dimensional dynamic array in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

Given m points in the plane. Number of xy coordinates must be
entered via the keyboard. How to find this coordinates from xy? With two-dimensional dynamic array.

Now I have this but it's not working:

```
int **enterPoints (int m) {
    int i, **points;
    scanf("%d",&m);
    points = (int **)malloc(m*sizeof(int *));
    if (points != NULL) {
        for (i=0; i<m; i++) {
            *(points+i) = (int *)malloc(m*sizeof(int));
            if (*(points+i)==NULL)
                break;
        }
        {
            printf("enter %d points coord X and Y:", i+1);
            scanf("%d %d", &*(*(points+i)+0), &*(*(points+i)+1));
            *(*(points+i)+2)=0;
        }
    }
    free(points);
    return points;
}
```

Comment: what is not working? Is it not compiling? Is it giving wrong results? And What is your acutal question? what do you mean with "How to find this coordinates from xy?"

Comment: Generally speaking, the forumla is `Value = *(ArrayStartingPoint + ((x*y.Length+y)*sizeof(array type)))`

Comment: thanks for a formula something like that I wished to use .I cant input numbers for x and y. Now I can't run the program...And dont understand why. Its dont do anythink I click run and build and nothing happens. Im begginer in c programing...

Comment: You need to learn to format your code so it is readable and comprehensible.  What you've got there is excruciatingly badly formatted.  You don't want to `free(points);` before you return the pointer.  Your second `malloc()` is wasting space.  If I specify 1 coordinate, it doesn't allocate enough space; if I specify 1,000,000 coordinates, it tries to allocate a million million integers over the course of a million allocations (and most machines don't have that much memory — 4 TiB needed).  The `m` should be `2`.

Comment: I feel like a hero for formatting that.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int **enterPoints (int m){
    int i, **points;
    //scanf("%d",&m);//already get as argument
    if(m<=0)
        return NULL;
    points = (int**)malloc(m*sizeof(int*));
    if (points != NULL){
        for (i=0; i<m; i++){
            points[i] = (int*)malloc(2*sizeof(int));
            if(points[i]!=NULL){
                printf("enter %d points coord X and Y:", i+1);fflush(stdout);
                scanf("%d %d", &points[i][0],&points[i][1]);
            }
        }
    }
    //free(points);//free'd regions is unusable
    return points;
}

int main(void){
    //test code
    int i, m, **points;
    //scanf("%d", &m);
    m = 3;
    points = enterPoints(m);
    for(i = 0; i < m; ++i){
        printf("(%d, %d)\n", points[i][0], points[i][1]);
        free(points[i]);
    }
    free(points);
    return 0;
}
```